# Program behaves differently when I use a different assignment operator on a pointer variable

Tags: go

I was playing around when I encountered this strange behavior:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var appConfig *map[string]interface{}

func main() {
    // Works fine
    //appConfig = &map[string]interface{}{
    //  "name": "marcus",
    //}
    // Causes panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    appConfig := &map[string]interface{}{
        "name": "marcus",
    }
    fmt.Println("Config:", *appConfig)
    getName()
}

func getName() {
    fmt.Println("Name is ", (*appConfig)["name"])
}
```

I don't understand why would the program crash if I use the short variable declaration `:=` instead of the plain `=` assignment operator. Could someone enlighten me as to the reason behind the difference in behaviours? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And: Do not use pointers to maps (useless in most cases).

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are facing is due to variable shadowing. In your second example, when you use the short variable declaration (:=), you create a new local variable named `appConfig` within the main function's scope, which is different from the global `appConfig` variable you declared at the beginning of your code.

When you use the plain assignment operator (=), you assign a pointer to a map to the global `appConfig` variable. This means that when you call `getName()`, it can access the global `appConfig` variable and get the correct value.

However, when you use the short variable declaration (:=), you create a new local `appConfig` variable within the scope of the `main` function, and the global `appConfig` variable remains uninitialized (nil). When you call `getName()`, it tries to access the global `appConfig` variable, which is still nil, resulting in a panic.

**TL;DR:** You need to use the plain assignment operator (=) to ensure you're assigning the value to the global `appConfig` variable.